# What is the connection between Binomial and Jeffreys Test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

Normally, I am testing the calibration of a probability of default model with the binomial test. The ECB is suggesting the Jeffreys Test.

Are they related in any way? Is the Jeffreys test superior to the simple binomial test in any way?

The goal is to compare forecast rate of success (defaults) with actual success.

[image]

See https://www.bankingsupervision.europa.eu/banking/tasks/internal_models/shared/pdf/instructions_validation_reporting_credit_risk.en.pdf

Comment: As documented, the spelling is Jeffreys.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the number of defaults is very small, these tests are essentially the same.

See, for example, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.03698.pdf), pp. 15-16.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).